# How to avoid "Property 'click' does not exist on type 'Element'.ts(2339)" error

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript

I am trying to use the below jQuery code in my Angular app, needed for a select dropdown component.

```
document.querySelector('.dropdown-el').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  $(this).toggleClass('expanded');
  $('#' + $(e.target).attr('for')).prop('checked', true);
});
$(document).click(function() {
  $('.dropdown-el').removeClass('expanded');
});
```

The issue is, that I've got a TS error: `Property 'click' does not exist on type 'Element'.` when trying to use it. Is there any way to avoid this one?

Comment: What are you trying to do here, 99.9% of the time you dont need jQuery. And if you want to modify classes, you should use the angular way

Answer (score 0):

Click doesnt exist on an Element which is what is returned by the `document.querySelector()`. You need to cast it as an `HTMLElement`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast your element into the HTMLElement via

```
let myElement: HTMLElement = document.querySelector() as HTMLElement;
myElement.click();
```

Hope this helps.